# IOS NSString decode not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uialertview

I am receiving a string from the internet but i cant find a way to transform the special char and them show in on an alert box.
This is the string:

```
@"Sorry, your search doesn\u0027t have any result"
```

i know i could do something like this to work around

```
[response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0027" withString:@"'"];
```

but i wanted a solution that would work for any character

i have already tried several solution but none seam to work, and i don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
NSString *escapedStr = @"Sorry, your search doesn\\u0027t have any result";
NSString *unescapedStr = [NSString
            stringWithCString:[escapedStr cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
            encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"unescapedStr = %@", unescapedStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[response cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This should work.